# Where do I find ioctl EVIOCGRAB documented?

Tags: linux, documentation, ioctl

I want to use the `ioctl` `EVIOCGRAB` function in a C based program, and from googling around I have found various bits of example source code that use the function, but I am struggling to find explicit documentation that correctly describes how to correctly use it.

I see that from [ioctl(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl.2.html), `ioctl` function is defined as

```
int ioctl(int d, unsigned long request, …);
```

And that:

```
   The third argument is an untyped pointer to memory.  It's traditionally char
   *argp (from the days before void * was valid C), and will be so named
   for this discussion.
```

And I hoped to find `EVIOCGRAB` listed in [ioctl_list(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl_list.2.html), but it wasn't.

So I don't *know* what the third argument should be for the `EVIOCGRAB` function.  After seeing various bits of example code all I can do is *assume* that a non-zero value grabs the device and that a zero value releases it.

Which I got from random code examples like

```
int grab = 1;
ioctl(fd, EVIOCGRAB, &grab);
..
ioctl(fd, EVIOCGRAB, NULL);
```

or

```
ioctl(fd, EVIOCGRAB, (void*)1);
..
ioctl(fd, EVIOCGRAB, (void*)0);
```

or

```
ioctl(fd, EVIOCGRAB, 1);
..
ioctl(fd, EVIOCGRAB, 0);
```

(Which seems to smell a bit of cargo cult programming.)

So where can I find a definitive explanation of the `EVIOCGRAB` control parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A *definitive* explanation you can at least find in the kernel sources, more specifically `drivers/input/evdev.c`:

```
 static long evdev_do_ioctl(struct file *file, unsigned int cmd,
                            void __user *p, int compat_mode)
 {
 […]
     switch (cmd) {
     […]
     case EVIOCGRAB:
         if (p)
             return evdev_grab(evdev, client);
         else
             return evdev_ungrab(evdev, client);
     […]
     }
 […]
 }
```

As I understand, everything that evaluates to »false« (`0`) will lead to `evdev_ungrab` (`(void*)0`, `0`, …), everything that's »true« (not `0`) will cause an `evdev_grab` (`(void*)1`, `1`, `0xDEADBEEF`…).

One thing worth mentioning is that your first example,

```
int grab = 1;
ioctl(fd, EVIOCGRAB, &grab);
..
ioctl(fd, EVIOCGRAB, NULL);
```

only works unintentionally.  It's not the value *inside* of `grab`, but the fact that `&grab` is non-zero (you could have guessed this, since the counter-case isn't `grab = 0; ioctl(…, &grab);` but `ioctl(…, NULL);`. Funny. :)

Comment: Thank you for that. Yep the source is definitive (assuming that is the source being used on my system!), but documentation somewhere would have been nice.  As for that &grab example (which I knew was fishy and is not *my* code), I have seen that in multiple locations - including in a selected answer on stackoverflow.com